# best way to select columns from data.table by type

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for an elegant or efficient way to select columns in `R`'s `data.table`.

Personally I value a flexible approach.

Therefore I tend to refer to columns by their characteristics rather than their names.

For example, I want to set the values of all columns to lower case.

If I include all columns in this operation, like so

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, tolower),.SDcols = names(dt)]
```

numeric and integer columns, too, will be converted to (lower case) character.

This is undesirable, and hence I first identify all character columns as folows:

```
char_cols <- as.character(names(dt[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) which(is.character(x)))]))
```

and subsequently pass `char_cols` to .SDcols

```
dt[ , lapply(.SD, tolower), .SDcols = char_cols ]
```

If instead, all your columns are character (for example to avoid type conversion issues while reading the data) I would go about it like this

```
char_cols <- as.character(names(dt[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) which(all(is.na(as.numeric(x)))))]))
```

One should be certain however, that no column is of mixed type: i.e. contains some character strings and some numeric values.

Does anyone have a suggestion to approach this more elegantly, or more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a logical/character vector to `.SDcols`.

For character columns, we can do

```
library(data.table)
cols <- names(Filter(is.character, dt))
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, tolower), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: That is definitely more elegant. What about the second case. I load all my data as character type to avoid conversion issues with e.g. dates. Can you think of a better way to select those columns that are actual character type?

Comment: @o_v You can use `type.convert` to get data in their respective classes. `dt <- type.convert(dt, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: So I think the disadvantage of the ```SDcols = sapply(dt, is.character)``` solution is that I am only left with the character columns. So if I want to keep both character and numeric columns, I'm still better of with my solution.

Comment: See updated answer. This will help you to retain all the columns in `dt`.

Comment: Neat! I knew I was going about it too cumbersomely.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
cols <- names(which(sapply(dt, is.character)))
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, tolower), .SDcols = cols]
```